# Security salt in password hash changed

Tags: security, cakephp, passwords, password-encryption

Hashed password by using security salt is more secure than plain text password.

Should we change the salt from time to time for more secure?
Then users can't login with current password when the salt is changed.
Does it means we need to reset the password for every password record when the salt changed?

What If we lost  the security salt forever?
(someone changed it , or salt file deleted without permission ,etc..)

Comment: If you change the salt, all existing passwords with the old salt are invalidated. If you've lost the app's salt - all existing passwords are invalidated. It's actually not a good practice to use the same salt for all passwords - or to use simple hashes at all. Instead what you should be doing nowadays is to use php's [built-in password functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php)

Comment: Interesting reason to close this question, it may be a duplicate, but surely it is not opinion based.

Comment: @martinstoeckli The first question asked is: `Should we change the salt from time to time for more secure?` - you _don't_ think that's a question which will attract opinion-based answers? For example, you've bypassed completely that the question is about using a simple salted sha1 hash and gone straight for promoting current best practice instead.

Comment: `clearly say that changing a salt will not increase security` - it does if the salt is known =).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't. That would cause the problems you mentioned. Rather, if you wanted a more random salt, you could make it a function of data about the user. Like you could salt their password with the username, the creation date of their account, and even store a random number generated when they create their account that you can salt their password with.

To further explain the last part, what I mean is, when they create the account, generate a random number. Store the number in the database and salt their password with it (and maybe the other stuff mentioned above), then store the hash of the salted password. Next time they try to log in, retrieve the random number associated with their account (from the DB) and salt the submitted password in the same way you salted the original when they created their account, then hash it and compare it with the hash in the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the PHP functions [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), they will handle the creation of a secure salt and add them to the resulting hash-value, so you can store it to a single database field.

Changing the salt won't help in any way, it is not even possible, since you don't know the original password. A salt prevents to use a single rainbow-table to get all passwords at once, an attacker would have to build a rainbow-table for each password. With changing the salt you do not make this any harder.

Maybe another angle of view is even easier to understand. The salt shall make it harder to find the original password with a rainbow-table, in case someone could steal your database with the hashes. If he is successful with cracking the password, he can use this password, regardless that you have changed the salt in the meantime.

**Edit:**

From @AD7six comments I get, that CakePHP currently uses a global salt from a configuration file. This is technically not a salt, rather it is a key or a pepper. An attacker needs this key to be able to crack the hashes (assuming the key is strong enough). If he has the privileges on the server to read this key, it will become useless, also changing the key will not make it any harder.

There is one single case where changing the key helps: if the database with the hashes was stolen without the key, and the attacker **later** gets access to the key, and the key has changed in the meantime.

If you really think about making all passwords invalid with changing the key, then have a look at another way to get the same advantage. You could encrypt the alreay calculated password-hash, this way you can exchange the key whenever you want. I tried to explain this more in depth in a [tutorial](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/hash/en/index.php).

Comment: Pointing at php's password functions is all well and good (and of course I'm not saying that current best-practice is a bad idea) but none of that is applicable to this question. It's also pretty clear you're not familiar with CakePHP which [uses a single application-wide salt](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.2/app/Config/core.php#L222-L225) if simple password hashing is used (which is the default for bc and doesn't change until CakePHP 3.0 is released). Overall this answer simply doesn't help.

Comment: @AD7six - You are right that i do not know CakePHP, but doesn't it use the class [SimplePasswordHasher](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-SimplePasswordHasher.html) to hash passwords with BCrypt?

Comment: [No](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/SimplePasswordHasher.php#L41). [The auth component doesn't specify a hash by default](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/SimplePasswordHasher.php#L31) - which [falls back to sha1](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/Security.php#L122). [A different password hasher class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BlowfishPasswordHasher.php) is used for blowfish.

Comment: ... which has to be [explicitly enabled](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-bcrypt-for-passwords) as changing the default would be a b/c break.

Comment: @AD7six - That's scary - i couldn't imagine that, thanks for pointing it out. I edited my answer to cover this situation.